# How to escape pipe character "|" for formatting purposes in jq?

Tags: jq

I would like to escape the pipe character "|" in my output so that I can use it as a separator. Not sure how to escape it, though. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

It does not need to be escaped, only quoted, e.g.

```
1, "|", 2
```

or

```
"\(input)|\(input)"
```